# Wildfly 13 and EJB 2.1 compatibility issue and RelativeContext Classcast issue

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x, ejb-2.x, wildfly-13

Can anyone help to solve the below issue:

I am trying to upgrade my application server from `JBOSS 6` to `Wildfly 12/13`.

My Application is `EJB` based. When i am using `Jboss 6`, I was using `Jdk 1.7`

Now for Wildfly, I'm using `jdk 1.8`.

And, while upgrading to Wildfly, previous `jndi` settings wasn't working so I updated `jndi configurations` from

configurations file:

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory

PROVIDER_URL = jnp://localhost:1099

URL_PKG_PREFIXES = org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces

JNDI_VOOR_DS=java:/VOORSDB
```

to:

```
INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory

PROVIDER_URL = remote+http://localhost:8080

URL_PKG_PREFIXES = org.jboss.ejb.client.naming

JNDI_VOOR_DS=java:/VOORSDB
```

Now i am getting error as:

```
ERROR [com.aithent.voor.service.ServiceLocator] (ServerService ThreadPool -- 79) Exception whichle retrieving the home object for the EJB :UserServiceEJB 

ERROR [com.aithent.voor.service.ServiceLocator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeContext cannot be cast to javax.ejb.EJBHome 

ERROR [com.aithent.voor.service.ServiceFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeContext cannot be cast to javax.ejb.EJBHome
```

This is my ServiceLocator class:

```
    private ServiceLocator() throws Exception{
        createContext();
    }

    public void createContext() throws Exception{
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        cachedObject=new HashMap(10,0.8f);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getPropertyValue(WebConstants.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY));
        System.out.println(ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getPropertyValue(WebConstants.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY));

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getPropertyValue(WebConstants.PROVIDER_URL));
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getPropertyValue(WebConstants.URL_PKG_PREFIXES));
        env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        context = new WildFlyInitialContext(env);
        System.out.println("context: "+context);
        log.debug("ServiceLocator createContext method ends ");

    }    

    public EJBHome getHome(String ejbName) throws Exception{
        EJBHome ejbHome = null;
        log.debug("ServiceLocator getHome() starts ");
        try{
            System.out.println("Context: "+context);
            if(context != null){
                Object home = context.lookup("ejb:/"+ejbName);
                System.out.println(home);
                ejbHome = (EJBHome) home;
                System.out.println(ejbHome);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Exception whichle retrieving the home object for the EJB : " + ejbName);
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        log.debug("ServiceLocator getHome() ends ");
        return ejbHome;
    }
```

I even added jboss-client from wildfly-13 - bin/client folder. I tried almost everyway posted in other Q&A's but nothing worked.

I didn't understand how to attach files, if anyone guide me, i will attach server.log and standalone-full.xml for review.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on a basic HelloWorld project for EJB. 
I am using wildfly 14.0.1.

It magically started working when I removed the "ejb:" from the JNDI string "ejb:ejbsample-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld!com.ejbsample.HelloWorld"

If it would help please check the [server](https://gitlab.com/divijen/demoejbserver) and [client](https://gitlab.com/divijen/demoejbclient) code.